# How do I create a gif with a transparent background using Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

How do I create a .gif with a transparent background using Adobe Photoshop?

It's a bit late in the evening to ask my web developer to do this. Here's a screenshot of the image I've created:

[image: example image]

But I don't want white around the letters — it should look more like it does here: http://wordfruit.com

Here's what I've done:

- I downloaded the original .gif from the website files.
- When I open it in Photoshop, the layer is locked and I can't create a new layer…
- … so I copy pasted it into a new .psd document and edited that
- finally saved it as a .gif

Comment: As a professional UX Designer, I would always prefer PNG over GIF as it has alpha channel transparency and better compression. Meaning you are not losing a color to set it as the transparent one. My developer and I just got into a debate, he wants me to send him GIFs and I told him to stick to his profession of coding and ill stick to mine as a Graphic Designer.

Answer (score 15):

When you save a GIF (export for web) you have the option to select a color to make it transparent. note that you only get to pick ONE color, so you will typically end up with halo's around your image where it blends from your image into the original background color.

You're better off getting the original PSD file and then saving it as a transparent PNG.

Answer (score 2):

answer is based on what i understood :|

try this with the way your doing

- download  your gif image from  the web site
- Open in photoshop go to image > mode > select rgb color(do notice in your gif image right now its indexed color)

[image: image from google]

- when you create new document make sure your using transparent background

[image: image from photoshopforce]

now paste you image and save this as gif.

For saving gif see this : [Create transparent gif (Please mind only save section)](http://www.photoshopforce.com/tutorials/create-transparent-images/index.php)

---

Now my Advice on this  your designer/Developer using image sprite so it is hard for you to do the edits the way you want to, better you edit original psd and than save and use it, what your doing  isn't according to your designer/developer  they are using something else and your doing something else ...

---

sort and sweet suggestion : Find the original psd, edit your text and save it as .gif else wait for the designer.the way you are doing, it's waste according to me.

Hope this will help a bit..

Comment: koiyu i think his own image sprite was the easiest way to make him understood isnt it?